# How can we render a random partial in a Slim template within a Sinatra application?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

Given [a really simple Sinatra application](https://github.com/johnsyweb/sinatra-slim-random-partial/tree/as-asked):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim/include'

get '/' do
  @specifically = %W(milk bread cheese).sample
  slim :home
end
```

Where [`views/home.slim`](https://github.com/johnsyweb/sinatra-slim-random-partial/blob/as-asked/views/home.slim) looks like this:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Don't forget the stuff

  body
    include reminder
```

We can see that `reminder` is included as a bare word (rather than a `String`).

In [`views/reminder.slim`](https://github.com/johnsyweb/sinatra-slim-random-partial/blob/as-asked/views/reminder.slim), I want to include the random partial represented by the variable `@specifically`:

```
p Remember the things!

include @specifically
```

This raises a `Temple::FilterError` at `/`: `'@specifically.slim' not found`.

How can I get Slim to render `milk.slim` (or whatever) here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rubber ducking](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) this [worked](https://github.com/johnsyweb/sinatra-slim-random-partial/commit/b10203b0d5fcb77f9fedb30d3508b05fb0c27264)!

Instead of

```
include @specifically
```

Use

```
== slim @specifically.to_sym
```

Comment: I couldn't find this approach documented anywhere so will leave this answer for others to find rather than remove the question.